# Rudin Chapter 8, Theorem 5 Confusion

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

The problem statement is as follows:

*Show that there exist $S = (-R, R) \subset \mathbb{R}, E \subset S, \sum c_n x^n$* such that:

- $E$ is countably infinite,
- The limit points of $E$ are not contained in $S$,
- $\sum c_n x^n$ converges for $x \in S$,
- $\sum c_n x^n$ = 0 for $x \in E$,

but there exists $x \in S$ such that $\sum c_n x^n \neq 0$.

This problem essentially is asking to show that the assumptions for Rudin's Theorem 8.5 are necessary.

I have been starring at this problem for quite some time now and have made no headway on it. Any suggestions on how to proceed or think about it?

Comment: **Hint:** Try the Taylor series of $\sin(1/(1-x))$ on $(-1, 1)$.